# Deleting Giant Log File Didn't Free Up Space

Tags: disk-usage, log, syslog

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and I had to delete syslog.1 from /var/log/ folder after it filled up to 20GB+ due to a bug with VLC and my NVIDIA driver.

I opened nautilus with sudo and right clicked move to trash but the file never appeared there, I was guessing due to its size. The file disappeared and was replaced with a new clean log file a short while later.

My disk usage analyzer shows the disk with only 19 GB but nautilus shows the drive with 0/48.5 GB

I'm guessing some process is holding the file but I don't know how to find it or end it.

Comment: I believe I right clicked it in nautilus as admin and said move to trash. It never appeared there though, so I assumed it was deleted.

Answer (score 3):

To find large files held open by some process:

```
sudo lsof / | \
   awk '{if($7 > 1048576) print $7/1048576 "MB" " " $9 }' | \
   sort -n -u
```

But, you should check for deleted (but open) files as well, with

```
sudo lsof / | \
    egrep 'PID|\(deleted\)'
```

These command sequences are so handy that I've made them aliases. The quoting is difficult, so here's what I put in my `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
alias bigopenfiles='sudo lsof / | awk '\''{if($7 > 1048576) print $7/1048576 "MB" " " $9 }'\'' | sort -n -u'
alias deletedfiles='sudo lsof / | egrep '\''PID|\(deleted\)'\'''
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely the log file is still open as described here:

- [Best way to free disk space from deleted files that are held open](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182077/best-way-to-free-disk-space-from-deleted-files-that-are-held-open)

The answers go into great details but basically you can:

- kill the process that opened the log file
- `truncate` the log file which is my preferred method.